# Normal subgroup equal kernel

Tags: group-theory

Given a group $G$ and two subgroups $N,K$ and its inclusion map :
$$j_{1} : N \to G$$
$$j_{2} : K \to G$$
Extend to the homomorphism : 
$$j : N*K \to G$$
Let $A$ be a normal subgroup of $N*K$ and $A \subset Ker j$ and the map induced by $j$ :
$$ k : (N*K)/A \to G$$
Is an isomorphism then $A = Ker j$ .

Comment: You mean the statement $A = Ker j$ is true ?

Comment: I mean $k$ is an isomorphism and I need $A = Ker j$

Comment: OK, sorry I misunderstood. If $g \in {\rm Ker}(j)$ then $gA \in {\rm Ker}(k)$. So if $k$ is an isomorphism then $gA = A$, hence $g \in A$, and so $A = {\rm Ker}(k)$.